# How to ensure thread read last variable value?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, synchronization

I have a multi threaded C application as following (where S is a global Shared variable):

```
Thread 1   Thread 2   Thread 3       Thread 4

while(1)   while(1)    while(1)       while(1)
 read S     read S      read S
   |          |          |             sleep 1 second
   |          |          |             stop all other threads
   |          |          |             write to share variable S
   |          |          |             resume all other threads
 read S     read S      read S
   |          |          |             
   |          |          |             
 barrier     barrier   barrier
```

It runs on top of a 3.11 linux kernel on different intel multicores architectures.

As suggested in a previous question [How to properly suspend threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854580/how-to-properly-suspend-threads) I am using a custom barrier to suspend/resume my threads. Threads 1 to 3 are reading the share variable S several times in the body of their infinite loop. My question is, how to ensure that when they are restarted they all read the last value written by thread 4 starting at the begining of their infinite loop ?

I guess that a mutex lock/unlock solution before reads and writes to S should work but I am wondering how can I avoid it because I am already ensuring that there is no concurrent access to the variable thanks to the control I have on the threads with the suspend/resume mechanism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you need ensure that the write to `S` in Thread 4 is visible to the other threads when they are released from the barrier -- and not before.  Happily, the custom barrier has a mutex, and `barrier_continue()` acquires and releases it when the worker threads are released.  When the workers restarted they will acquire and release the mutex.  So, things will work if the sequence of operations is:

1. *all* worker threads `pthread_cond_wait()` (under the mutex);
2. thread 4 *then* acquires the mutex and writes to `S`;
3. thread 4 restarts the workers by `pthread_broadcast()`;
4. thread 4 releases the mutex;
5. the workers all (re-)acquire and release the mutex and read `S`.

...because the acquisition and release of the mutex are synchronization points.  (Actually, 3 and 4 can be done in the other order.)

To achieve this, when Thread 4 decides to halt the worker pthreads it needs a way to then wait for them all to come to a stop, so that it can then write `S` and restart the workers.  This is an extra step after your "stop all other threads", where you "wait for all other threads to stop".  That would also involve locking the custom barrier mutex... so there is actually no extra locking required.

The problem here is not so much making sure that the write of `S` is visible to the workers *after* they are restarted, the problem is ensuring that the new `S` is *not* visible *before* they come to a stop.  You could have a `Next_S` variable, which is picked up by the workers after they are restarted.  Thread 4 could "stop all other threads", write to `Next_S` and then restart all the workers.  The workers, after the restart, could read the `Next_S`, and not before.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you pause the threads and no concurrent accesses can happen you still need to tell the compiler that the value may asynchronously change. If you can use C11 and `S` has a simple type like `int` you can use an [`atomic_int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) and save yourself the overhead of putting threads to sleep and waking them up.

I am unsure from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24867951/3484570) if the threads are paused at a defined point rather than possibly after reading half of `S`. Assuming that never happens the following should be safe even though I can already feel the outcry: Since no data race is possible on `S` and you just need to prevent the compiler from storing `S` in a register you can make `S` `volatile` or access it through a `volatile` pointer. That will not work if you use `S` to synchronize other data, but it does work for `S` itself.

Comment: Threads are only paused inside the barrier, so at the end of the loop and not between the 2 readings of S. S is already declared volatile (if the compiler decided to store it in a register I will never see the modified value and I see it). My problem is that it seems "to take time" for S change to be visible, and I guess this is related to memory ordering issues

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pthread (prior to C++11,) you can guard with posix semaphore lock and unlock before after access of the shared variable, use pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock (example as in http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp06/cs241/Discussions/cs241-ds3.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as stated in my answer, I guess that this solution would work and I am looking for another solution to avoid this overhead.